# After a while slideshow is stopped ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

why not work true following code and after 5 min stopped?

```
var x = 0;
var s = 0;

function cicle() {
    if (x < 2) {
        $("#slide").animate({
            "right": "-=893px"
        }, 1500);
        x++;
        s++;
    } else {
        x = 0;
        s++;
        $("#slide").animate({
            "right": "0px"
        }, 1000);
    }
};
var a = setInterval("cicle()", 5000);
if (s == 10) {
    clearInterval(a);
    var a = setInterval("cicle()", 5000);
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rxYQ9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first parameter of `setInterval` to `cicle`:

```
var a = setInterval(cicle, 5000);
if (s == 10) {
    clearInterval(a);
    var a = setInterval(cicle, 5000);
}
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Maybe it would be better to stop the animation before adding a new one:

```
function cicle() {
    if (x < 2) {
        $("#slide").stop().animate({
            "right": "-=893px"
        }, 1500);
        x++;
        s++;
    } else {
        x = 0;
        s++;
        $("#slide").stop().animate({
            "right": "0px"
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```